# VB.NET not seeing some classes

Tags: vb.net, class, shared, public, option-strict

One of my classes seems to be invisible to the rest of my project. I wonder if I somehow have to initialize it before I can use its public stuff.

The functions and methods of `Class1` immediately appear in IntelliSense, but `Class2` is treated like a general (unknown) object.

I have some `Public Shared` functions in `Class1` and `Class2`. I can call functions using

```
Class1.myPublicSharedFunction()
```

normally. However when I try this with any function from `Class2`, I get the error:

```
Error   1   Option Strict On disallows late binding.
```

even though their types are of course declared. If I copy and paste a working function from `Class1` to `Class2` and try to call it, it starts giving the same error. Any test function I declare in `Class2` doesn't get its type recognized and is thus accused of trying to do late binding.

Both classes are public, and all the functions mentioned are `Public Shared`. I don't understand what makes the classes work differently. It's as if I needed to load or compile `Class2` before VB knows its function types, but these things are supposedly automatic in VB.

What could be the cause of this?

When I begin typing `Class2.`, IntelliSense lists is as a function, while `Class1` is recognized as a class.

EDIT:
If I copy the exact contents of `Class2` into new class, only changing the line `Public Class ...` to the new name, everything works as normal. I thought it might be that the name was too long, so I copied the class to `AnotherClassWithAReallyLongName`, but this one worked too.
However, if I delete `class2`, and re-add it and paste back its contents, it still won't work.

Comment: Can you share with us the class declarations and also the way you are using the classes from the code?

Comment: @Davide The contents of the classes are fine, because everything works if I copy class2 to another class. There seems to be something wrong with the name of class2, will update my question.

Comment: Do you have something else in your code, either written by you or in a different namespace called 'class2' ? If now you've renamed it and type `class2.` Into vb do you get any intellisense?

Comment: @CResults Bingo, I found that the following had magically been added to the class:
 "Private Function FloatingNumbersWhileAdd() As Object
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Function".

That solved it. What a waste of time, I'm not used to such things appearing automatically. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comment you have something else in your code named `Class2’ that is hiding your new class definition. Remove it/rename it and your class will work.

Comment: Yes, thank you!
Do you know under what circumstances that code block would appear? Because I certainly did not put it there.

Comment: It sounds like code that would be added by VS to sy "don't forget to implement this function" - for example when you override a baee class which has functions tagged with `MustOverride`. In the partiular instance i'm not 100% sure though!